# Show/hide a certain number of Excel rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm creating a loan repayment calculator schedule with Excel 2010, where the user inputs loan amount, interest rate and duration (in months), and the calculator returns the repayment value for each month. I would like the calculator to show/hide rows based on the duration of the loan (es. 12 months=show 12 rows). Is this possible?

Comment: Easy answer: Yes. Not that i want to insinuate something - but this sounds so much like an assigned homework. Please see the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - and explain what you have tried so far (we're here to help not to do the work for you...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommendation: Don't bother using VBA to hide rows automatically - instead, use conditional formatting to simply blank any cells which don't have data. This is simpler, and doesn't require your workbook to be macro-enabled.

For example - assume rows 11-22 are months from Jan-Dec. Assume Column A is, for example, the amount of interest paid in that period, based on a formula. We know that if there is no interest paid in the period, that period is not relevant, so the entire row can be hidden based on whether column A = 0.

Select rows 11-22, for as many columns as you have data (let's say column A - column G). Click on the Conditional Formatting button, and Add New Rule. Click the last option of the rule types, 'add custom rule', with the formula:

```
=$A11=0
```

Whenever column A equals 0, for each specific row, the rule for that row will say TRUE. So go to the Formatting Options of the conditional format rule, and make the font white, and the background white, and the borders gone.